# Append function overwrites existing data in slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice, portaudio

I wrote a small application which records data from a sound card and stores the data in an array for later processing.

Whenever new data is available, portaudio executes the callback `record`. Within the callback I append the data to the array `RecData.data`.

The golang builtin function `append` adds as expected another element to the slice, **but for whatever reason also overwrites all existing elements within the array with exactly the same data**.

I have been trying to isolate the problem for more than two days, without success.

Here is a stripped down version of the code, which works and shows the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
//    "reflect"

    "github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio"
)

type RecData struct{
    data [][][]float32
}

func main() {

    var inputChs int = 1
    var outputChs int = 0
    var samplingRate float64 = 48000
    var framesPerBuffer int = 3 //for test purpose that low. Would normally be 1024 or 2048

    rec := RecData{make([][][]float32, 0, 1000)}

    portaudio.Initialize()

    stream, err := portaudio.OpenDefaultStream(inputChs, outputChs, samplingRate, framesPerBuffer, rec.record)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer stream.Close()
    stream.Start()
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    }
}

// callback which gets called when new data is in the buffer
func (re *RecData)record(in [][]float32) {
    fmt.Println("Received sound sample: ")
    fmt.Println(in)
    re.data = append(re.data, in)
    fmt.Println("Content of RecData.data after adding received sound sample:")
    fmt.Println(re.data, "\n")
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500) //limit temporarily the amount of data read
    // iterate over all recorded data and compare them
    /*
    for i, d := range re.data{
        if reflect.DeepEqual(d, in){
                fmt.Printf("Data at index %d is the same as the recorded one, but should not be!\n", i )
        }
    }*/
}
```

**2. Update**

This is the application output:

```
Received sound sample:
[[0.71575254 1.0734825 0.7444282]]
Content of RecData.data after adding received sound sample:
[[[0.71575254 1.0734825 0.7444282]]]

Received sound sample:
[[0.7555193 0.768355 0.6575008]]
Content of RecData.data after adding received sound sample:
[[[0.7555193 0.768355 0.6575008]] [[0.7555193 0.768355 0.6575008]]]

Received sound sample:
[[0.7247052 0.68471473 0.6843796]]
Content of RecData.data after adding received sound sample:
[[[0.7247052 0.68471473 0.6843796]] [[0.7247052 0.68471473 0.6843796]] [[0.7247052 0.68471473 0.6843796]]]

Received sound sample:
[[0.6996536 0.66283375 0.67252487]]
Content of RecData.data after adding received sound sample:
[[[0.6996536 0.66283375 0.67252487]] [[0.6996536 0.66283375 0.67252487]] [[0.6996536 0.66283375 0.67252487]] [[0.6996536 0.66283375 0.67252487]]]


.... etc ....
```

As we one can see, over time, the size of the slice is growing, but instead of just appending the data, the data in the array gets also overwritten.

This should not happen. `portaudio` provides in the callback a `[][]float32` with the audio sample recorded from the sound card. As you can see they are always different.

As mentioned, the code above is a stripped down version of my application. Usually I would record lets say 5 seconds, and then perform a Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT) over the samples to calculate the spectrum. I left this part away since it has no impact on this particular problem.

I would very much appreciate any help. Maybe somebody can point me out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `append` never re-writes existing data in the same array. `append` may need to allocate a new array when the slice doesn't have sufficient capacity, which of course requires _copying_ the data to the new backing array. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: No, the data gets clearly overwritten. It is also my understand that append does not re-write data, but I'm still facing the problem that after calling append in the callback, the existing data in the array is overwritten :-(

Comment: Maybe you could have some concurrent go routine that do this mess.

Comment: Please show an example of what you expect to see, and what you are seeing. You're appending `in` to the slice, then writing the error message if `in` is in the slice, which seems expected.

Comment: I couldn't find any usage of concurrent go coroutines in the portaudio library. I'm also not using any go coroutines within the application itself

Comment: Your output just looks like `in` contains the same values each time, not that the previous values are overwritten. `refpect.DeepEqual` isn't only checking for some sort of slice identity, it's iterating over each individual value.

Comment: I wonder if `portaudio` might be passing you the same slice every time (with different contents). Since you're putting the slice itself into `re.data`, every element might be a reference to the same slice. Try copying the data your callback receives instead.

Comment: Doesn't go copy everything by default?

Comment: I updated the example code and the output to show that on each execution of the callback, the variable `in` contains different data. You can see clearly that for strange reasons, that original data in the `Redata.data` array gets overwritten.

Comment: @DH1TW: the portaudio package is reusing the slice that is being provided to the callback. You need to copy the data into your own slice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buffer passed into the callback is reused by the portaudio package, so you are appending the same slice structure to your `data` slice. Each time the buffer allocated by portaudio overwrites the data, you see the results in every element of your `data` slice.

You will need to allocate new slices and make a copy of the data:

```
func (re *RecData) record(in [][]float32) {
    buf := make([][]float32, len(in))
    for i, v := range in {
        buf[i] = append([]float32(nil), v...)
    }
    re.data = append(re.data, buf)
```

Example: 
https://play.golang.org/p/cF57lQIZFU

Comment: got it! Thanks for the code snippet @JimB ! I confirm, now the data gets properly appended to `RecData.data`! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Instead of appending to `buf` every time, I would make `buf` the appropriate size in the first place. That way, only one allocation will happen for `buf`.

Comment: Actually I will change it to `make` in this example, but not quite for that reason (I usually just recommend people don't worry about it and use `append`, since it amortizes well and leaves cleaner code). Given the example data, the number allocations would be the same, except that we would be over-allocating memory, since the default `append` from 0 allocates a capacity of 2.